# Update fields from lookup object

Tags: apex

I have 2 custom objects. 
Custom object A has fields quantity and estimate
Custom object B has field price.
Custom object A has a Lookup to Custom Object B.
When a user enters a quantity on the custom object A fields, I need to go to custom object B and grab the price for those fields.  Bring it back and do some stuff.
So for the Class, what is the best approach to make sure the update works well.  My concern is that a user can edit up to 20 fields on record A and that they will be performing large data loads. Can I just use what I have so far?

```
global void beforeUpdate( SObject oldSo, SObject newSo )

list<objectA__c> objectAs = trigger.new; 
List<Id> objectBIDs = new List<Id>();
for (objectA__c a: objectAs)
{
objectBIDs.add(a.objectB__c);   
}

if (objectBIDs.size()>0){
map<Id,ObjectB__c> objectBMap = new map<Id,objectB__c>([select ID,price__c from objectB__c where id in :objectBids]);

for (objectA__c a: objectAs)
{
   if (objectBmap.containskey(a.objectB__c))
   {
     a.estimate__c = a.quantity__c * objectBmap.get(a.objectB__c).price__c;
     a.Building_Entry_Cost_Estimate__c = a.Building_Entry_Cost_Qty__c * objectBmap.get(a.objectB__c).Building_Entry_Price__c;
     a.City_Permits_Estimate__c  = a.City_Permits_Qty__c * objectBmap.get(a.objectB__c).City_Permits_Price__c;
     a.Delash_Fiber_Estimate__c  = a.Delash_Fiber_Qty__c * objectBmap.get(a.objectB__c).Delash_Fiber_Price__c;
   }
}
}
```

Thx
P

Comment: looks good to me; SOQL using indexed fields (the ObjectB Id will be very fast) and the trigger context will in most use cases be at most 200 Object A's

Comment: ok. I guess my concern was doing updates inside the for loop could cause an issue on data loads. I have update my initial question to include my method.

Comment: You are not doing explicit DML in the for loop.  The before update trigger will implicitly batch the updates of trigger.new in one update when trigger exits